# IOS Dynamic Tableviewcell, strange UILabel behavior

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview

I have a dynamic tableview that loads data from an XML file on the web. The prototype cell is simply two labels (stacked) and three buttons lining the bottom of the view. I added code to expand the size of the second label and cell height based on text length of the label. Some of the cells show the full 2nd label, while most only show the first line. And occasionally the cells will display the full 2nd label after I have rescrolled to them (off screen to on screen).
Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath code.

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"localdiningTableCell";

        mhgiLocalDiningCell *diningcell = [tableView
                                           dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (diningcell == nil) {
            diningcell = [[mhgiLocalDiningCell alloc]
                          initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                          reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        mhgiDiningXmlObject *object = [self.xmlParser.allItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        // Configure the cell...
        diningcell.nameLabel.text= [object Name];



        NSString *typeText = [object Type];
        NSString *addressText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@", [object Street], [object City], [object State]];
        NSString *distanceText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ miles from the hotel", [object Distance]];
        NSString *descrText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@", typeText, addressText, distanceText];


        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(260.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [descrText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake (diningcell.typeLabel.frame.origin.x, diningcell.typeLabel.frame.origin.y, 260.0f, labelSize.height);

        diningcell.typeLabel.frame = frame;
        diningcell.typeLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        diningcell.typeLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        diningcell.typeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
        diningcell.typeLabel.text = descrText;

        return diningcell;
```

Example,

Should look like this

```
  Label 1

  Label 2, with some long
  text that takes up more than
  one line
```

but looks like this

```
  Label 1

  Label 2, with some long
  .
  .
```

note, "." are not actually shown, just indicating the space for the label is provided. The text just seems to disappear on random cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Verify if you have auto layout enabled or disabled.
- Verify if you have property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
  set to YES or NO - you are setting frame ([see Adopting Auto
  Layout](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/adoption.html))
- Verify that you do not get constraint conflict warnings while running
  your code
- Why are you passing UITableViewCellStyleDefault value in your init
  function? Do you initialise your cell properly?

Instead of using frame you may want to define a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelHeight;
```

and then

```
float width = self.label.frame.size.width
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [descrText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
self.labelHeight.constant = labelSize.height;
```

Comment: The problem ended up being with the constraints not being fully defined for label 2. I added another constraint specifying the space to bottom and it now works. The height constraint was winning in most cases forcing the label to be one line. While not given as a specific answer, the "constraint conflict" made me think to check constraints.

Answer (score 0):

1.if you have a mhgiLocalDiningCell.xib just use

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"mhgiLocalDiningCell" owner:self options:nil];
    if ([nib count] > 0) {
        cell = nib[0];
    }
}
```

2.have you returned the right height of any row with

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

or

```
tableView.rowHeight = 44.0f;
```